# Implementation samples of Pluggable MIME Filter (preferably in C#)?

Tags: internet-explorer, mime-filter, browser-extension

Anyone know of a good sample implementation of a [Pluggable MIME Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(VS.85).aspx#Creating_a_Pluggable) for IE, preferably implemented in C#?  Or of a pluggable protocol handler?

thanks!

So far I have found

- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687287/why-isnt-my-ie-mime-filter-being-created-or-called) with sample code
- this sample:
  http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=3031&postcount=4
  (which is briefly documented [here](http://www.bsalsa.com/mime_filter.html)) (both from the SO question above)
- [This sample](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q260840) from MSFT (but not using C#)

Comment: The one I'm working on has become pretty unreliable under IE8, but if I can get it working well again I'll try to put together some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Microsoft support for a couple of weeks, we determined that MIME filters written in .NET do not work correctly.  There appear to be a number of thread-safety issues in the interop layers that cause random crashes of IE.

I've reimplemented my MIME filter in C++ following the same sample you linked to above, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Any chance you could post or email a sample?

Comment: The Microsoft sample is as good as anything I could provide.  I'm pretty much just using different code in the IInternetProtocol::Read() method that does what I need my filter to do.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/AspxProtocol.asp is my favorite.  Note, however, that using .NET for a protocol handler is generally going to incur a pretty significant performance cost, and there may be a versioning problem if there are other .NET-based components attempting to run in the browser that require a different version of the CLR.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DataProtocol.aspx is another option.