# Intercept an HTTP request at browser end to alter some html content

Tags: c#

I would like to do as follows. What would be the best way? A general answer will also be fine.

I would like to intercept an HTTP request at the client end to alter some html content. For example, I go to CNN.com and rather than an article that's displaying "Two LA Dogs marry",  it should say "Ridiculous title blocked".

It should be smooth that even a secure certificate won't be disturbed.

I am using C#.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: children parents, anyone who cares about what they could potentially be exposed to

Comment: The answer to this is easy all you have to do is Rediculous Title blocked and you have everything setup the way you need it to be.

Comment: This problem is not very well defined.  Is this software going to be used for multiple computers or for yourself?  When you say 'sensor bad things', do you really want to replace words as opposed to entirely blocking access to the objectionable content?  If you're offended by dogs marrying you probably don't want CNN's account of how they fell in love and their romantic honeymoon plans.  Based on the little information we have, your best bet, as suggested below is some sort of proxy.  That said, if you're looking for proxy software this question is better suited for SuperUsers vs SO.

Comment: -1 for "It should be smooth that even a secure certificate won't be disturbed.": THOU SHALL NOT lie about what is yours and what is not. If the site was SIGNED, then it's content WAS SIGNED, and if you modify it, it is 100% normal and positive to the users to view the content as signature-mismatched..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) via their [filter files](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/filter-file.html).  Their [fun filter](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#FILTER-FUN) is a good example of exactly the sort of substitutions you want to do.

To replace "Two LA Dogs Marry" with "Ridiculous Title Blocked" on cnn.com your action file would look something like this:

> ```
> { +filter{ridiculous-title-censor} }  
> .cnn.com
> ```

and your filter file would look like

> ```
> # FILTER: ridiculous-title-censor Remove ridiculous titles
> # This keeps CNN from getting too ridiculous
> #
> s/Two LA Dogs Marry/Ridiculous Title Blocked/ig
> ```

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what i need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another option if you're using Firefox is to use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) scripts. Here's an [example script](http://www.ironicsans.com/2007/01/idea_cnn_fortune_cookie_grease.html) which changes the main headline on cnn.com

If you're not familar with the Javascript coding needed to make Greasemoney scripts, you can use the [Platypus add-on](http://platypus.mozdev.org/) to edit the page in place and automatically generate a script file.

Answer (score 4):

Local HTTP proxy is possible and most generic approach.

I.e. you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if it works for you. I supports modifying requests/responses in addition to regular watching for traffic.

Comment: Thats alot i hope to give this a try!

Comment: Note that Fiddler is not just an app, it also has a library which makes it hostable inside your own process.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a proxy with HTTPListener.  But I would think if you wanted to do it right, you'll need a program that is more low level.

- Open 2 TCP Ports (80 & 443) and actively listen for incoming connections.
- Once received

  - Go out and make the request on behalf of the requester
- Retrieve HTTP Response
- Inspect and change the HTTP Response (where appropriate)

  - Perhaps modifying headers (where appropriate)
- Forward on the response to the requester

I'd start with a simple proxy that just forwards all requests and returns back all responses.  Once that is in place you can start inspecting the responses.

That is a good place to start.

Comment: By using a custom built proxy it could be used by any modern browser.

Answer (score 2):

Such an approach is the least efficient method of doing what you want to achieve.

If this is a client side application, the client may disable it and thus render it useless.
It is also hard to maintain and requires more complex programming to ensure that it works with SSL.

- If using a browser plugin, or toolbar, it would need to be made for a specific browser.
- If using a listening server to intercept the HTTP request, this provides complexity and difficulty when the content is encrypted, also unnecessary overhead.
- If using a local proxy (meaning that the client's browser needs to point to a local proxy service), maybe the most effective client side method, but still have the disadvantages mentioned above (hard to maintain etc.)

**I believe that what you are looking to do is completely reinventing the wheel.**

The fact that you have offered a bounty begs the question that you indeed need to do this in C# and client side, but 'censoring bad things' means you need to prohibit content, and any client side method would eventually give the power to the client to remove this limitation.

Personally, I have had great success with [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) and it's [content adaptation features](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation).

This means, that the clients need to have a controlled Internet source. Meaning that, if they are all in a LAN and sharing a common Internet gateway, this is easily feasible if you have spare a server to act as a proxy.

I recommend you get a small linux box, which can have a simple Ubuntu Server Edition, then add Squid. The net is full of tutorials, but the level of implementation has become easy enough to do even without them.

I may have gone completely off-topic, but I hope I could assist.

Answer (score 1):

you can come to China ^_^
censorship like this is everywhere, you don't have to implement your own.

Ok, that is a joke, the answer is you can implement browser plugins for such kind of tasks. or maybe you need to implement a ROUTING filter ( GFW like ) on the router.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008423/1113272).

It can be done via a [Layered Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) on Windows.

From Wikipedia:

`"A Layered Service Provider (LSP) is a feature of the Microsoft Windows Winsock 2 Service Provider Interface (SPI). A Layered Service Provider is a DLL that uses Winsock APIs to insert itself into the TCP/IP stack. Once in the stack, a Layered Service Provider can intercept and modify inbound and outbound Internet traffic. It allows processing all the TCP/IP traffic taking place between the Internet and the applications that are accessing the Internet (such as a web browser, the email client, etc). "`

AdMuncher for example is intercepting and inserting http code to avoid ads. Another suggestion is to find an open-source ad blocking program and see how they've implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to intercept this for your own site?

In any case, it needs to be done in javascript or jQuery as C# is not a client-side language.

Comment: i would like it to happen at the browser application level.

Comment: an open source one? or ideally something happening a level before that?

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to develop a browser plugin or something similar. In that case, I have never done this before, so I have no clue how to do it. I would start by googling around for browser plugin development or something similar.

Comment: that is a great idea worth considering +1

Comment: _jaressloo_ is right, example of such plugin is AdBlock - checks for known elements in the DOM structure and sets `display: none` so they are not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

or, you can code a toolbar, or maybe a simple chrome addon, it's really easy but its not C#

you can search for libraries to monitor browsing trough proxy, like this:

http://httpproxynet.codeplex.com/

The same concept used by java in this project: 
http://www.charlesproxy.com/

sounds intresting, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I've implemented this feature for IE using [Plugable Mime Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28VS.85%29.aspx#Creating_a_Pluggable) so after I've searched about it in c# here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687287/why-isnt-my-ie-mime-filter-being-created-or-called) I've founded this post that should help you start with it.

Hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29) can be used for this type of thing.  Although, as stated here [INFO: Implementing HTTP-like Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303740): "For various reasons, Microsoft neither supports nor recommends that you replace or wrap the default HTTP protocol."