# Handling incoming URIs in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been making an application for the Bungie.net API in Winforms C# and need to get the authentication token. Since I cannot use the Winforms Webview (It'd be against the Terms of Use) I am passing it through the default browser. I can get it to open the browser and have the user login just fine but I cannot find information on how to catch the URI and send the token back to the application.

The simplest way to put it is I need to figure out how to do Step 3.2 of this tutorial: https://andrewdessin.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/bungie-nets-3rd-party-authentication-in-c/# except in Winforms instead of UWP. I may be looking at this the wrong way as I am fairly new to working with APIs and preforming authentication of this nature.

I have set a redirect URL on their site to "Authapp://" for testing purposes, I just need the application to catch the data being sent to "Authapp://" and can't find documentation on how to do so (If absolutely needed I am willing to make an application of a different type specifically to parse the data and send to the main Winforms app)

Comment: That's what I was worried about in my search. What application types would work better for this? (Other than UWP)

Answer (score 0):

That functionality does not exist (as built in) for Windows Forms apps, and it's pretty logical why: the management of an UWP app (install, uninstall, storage, etc.) is performed by Windows 10 in a *centralized* way, so it's pretty easy for Windows to just assgin a protocol to an UWP app and launch it when you open a specific URI in your browser (because it has more control).

For example, you can't intercept the Uninstall event of an UWP app (you don't have control over install / uninstall procedures).

On Windows Forms apps, instead, the developer has a lot more control over the entire process of managing an application, including install / uninstall, install location, etc. The output of a Windows Forms app is a simple executable that can be placed anywhere on the file system, so it's not so straight forward (for Windows) to search for it and launch it.

I know this is not a very exact answer, it's more like an intuitive approach of why this functionality works for UWP and not for WindowsForms.

**Additional approaches:**

- You can create a simple UWP app that just intercepts that callback and then you can send it to your WF app through HTTP or any other IPC mechanism.
- You can create a simple Web API app - this is the easiest way of catching a callback (you just intercept a GET request on your controller) and then send this to your WF app.
- You can try to intercept HTTP requests that are leaving your machine / your browser using approaces similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586794/intercept-an-http-request-at-browser-end-to-alter-some-html-content?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) one, but I don't think it would be an easy task.